# Installing a new Shimano compact crank on an older bottom bracket?

Tags: drivetrain

I would like to know if I could install a new Shimano compact crank on an older bottom bracket that has a center bolt extraction system? Do I need to change the spindle in the bottom bracket? Do I need a new crank extraction tool for the new crank system?
Thanks Mark

Comment: Which Shimano compact cranks? Newer Hollowtech II cranks will not be compatible with older square taper bottom bracket.  Any Hollowtech II crank will require a Hollowtech II bottom bracket.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes you mean the BB is [square taper](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/shimano-un26-square-taper-bottom-bracket/rp-prod34652) (one of many examples). Most crank pullers will do square taper, but you often need to use the tool slightly differently, such as by removing a cap. You probably can't change the spindle anyway, but you should be able to buy square taper cranks to suit you, and if not a new BB isn't too expensive.

The process is [essentially the same for all vaguely modern cranks](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/crank-removal-and-installation-three-piece#article-section-3).

Comment: Since there are two types of square taper just knowing it's square taper doesn't always help. You need the brand and a picture to correctly identify it.

Comment: @CaseyO'Neill that's true, but as we don't know the brands of anything I stuck to generalities.  [More info](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbtaper.html) for reference

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to remove the old bottom bracket completely and replace it with a Shimano BB. The make and model of your bike and the model of the crank with some pics are necessary to say any more than that in terms of specifics.

New Shimano cranks do require a new crank removal tool.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have indicated that the original BB is a Shimano so my guess is that the  new one should fit? Ive pulled off the old one many times to clean and change rings etc.

Comment: @MarkM you can't got by brand, as standard change.  The type of fitting is much more important.  Pictures or part numbers might help

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options. Replace the crank only, or replace both BB and crank.

If you replace just the crank you need one that is compatible with your existing BB, which is presumably a cartridge type with square taper (or possibly Octalink) spindle in a threaded shell. You don’t need to limit yourself to Shimano, there are a few brands that offer square taper cranks.

If the bike is old or well used the BB may need replacing, in that case you may also look at an external threaded BB and matching crank. Again, you can look at both Shimano and other brands.